# Comparing char array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, numbers, strcmp

I need help in c++. I want to compare char array. So, I did some coding. Unfortunately, it always comes out an error. I can't run it. Here I attached the code. Please help me fix this code. I want to check if the conclusion equal to sentence 1 then it is invalid but if it's not equal sentence 1 then it is valid. Help me, please. Thank you.

```
int number;
char sentence[number];
char rules[50];
char statement[50];
char premis1[100];
char premis2[100];
char conclusion[100];

cout<<"How many sentence you want to insert:";
cin>>number;
cout<<endl;

for(int i=0; i<number; i++)
{
    cout<<"Enter sentence ";
    cout<<i+1;
    cout<<":";
    cin>>sentence[i];
    cin.ignore();       
}

cout<<"Enter premis 1:";
cin.getline(premis1,100);
cin.ignore();
cout<<"Enter premis 2:";
cin.getline(premis2,100);
cin.ignore();


cout<<"Enter conclusion:";
cin.getline(conclusion,100);
cin.ignore();

for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
{
    if(strcmp(conclusion,sentence[0],)==0)
    {
        cout<<"Statement is invalid."<<endl;
        cout<<endl; 
    }
    else if(strcmp(conclusion,sentence[0])!=0)
    {
        cout<<"Statement is valid."<<endl;
    }
    else
        cout<<"exit"<<endl;         
}
```

Comment: This has an extra comma? strcmp(conclusion,sentence[0],). I'm assuming this isn't the full code, because this needs to be in main or a function... and you are adding the headers needed?

Comment: *Unfortunately, it always comes out an error.* -- Please be more specific.  What is the error?

Comment: number is not initialized yet you use it to initialize the array capacity: char sentence[number];

Answer (score 2):

Your mistakes you've made in the program:

1. You never initialized `number` but used in `sentence[]`, still it's invalid even after `number`'s declaration, that's because the compiler must know the exact value of the array length to be defined.
2. You've defined `sentence` as a char array but from your code, it seems like you wanted to store a full sentence into each element of array, which is impossible. Use `std::string` here.
3. You're doing `strcmp()` with the first character of char array, not the sentence with conclusion.

**Aside:** Please don't forget to include the important header files which are common to the code and we must assume your program is incomplete, because it has a lack of `main()` and statement(s), such as `strcmp(...,...',' - incomplete)`.

---

Redesigned the program (notice that `using namespace std` statement is used here because it's just a small program to demonstrate and for sake of simplicity and getting rid of `std::` prefixes everywhere):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int number = 0;
    vector<string> sentence;
    string tempSentence;
    string conclusion;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "How many sentences you want to insert? ";
    cin >> number;

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        fflush(stdin);
        cout << "Enter sentence " << (i + 1) << ": ";
        getline(cin, tempSentence);

        sentence.push_back(tempSentence);
    }

    cout << "Enter conclusion: ";
    getline(cin, conclusion);

    if (conclusion == sentence[0])
        cout << "The statement is invalid." << endl;
    else if (conclusion != sentence[0]) 
        cout << "The statement is valid." << endl;
    else
        cout << "EXIT" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I've taken `std::vector<>` of `std::string` here to insert a single string in defined number of sentences given in a dynamic way in each iteration (from `#include <vector>`) and used `std::string` rather than `char arr[]`, it's easy to compare strings here.

**Sample Output:**

```
$ g++ -o prog prog.cpp; ./prog

How many sentences you want to insert? 3 // --- INPUT
Enter sentence 1: This is the first sentence.
Enter sentence 2: This is the second sentence.
Enter sentence 3: This is the third sentence.
Enter conclusion: This is NOT the first sentence.
The statement is valid.   // first sentence != conclusion // --- OUTPUT
```